# Is there any shortcut key to align code content in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there any shortcut key to align code in Xcode? Just like Ctrl+K+D in Visual Studio?

Comment: In XCode 6, the default Re-Intent shortcut is ^I.Setting > Key-Bindings shows all default shortcuts, you can modify them if you want.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

<kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) is the shortcut key equivalent to Editor > Structure > Re-Indent ( in Xcode 6.4)

This will re-indent the line the cursor is on if no text is selected, or it will re-indent your selection.

Answer (score 9):

1.) Select the text you want to align,

then

2.) press <kbd>ctrl(^)</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: select text that want to align and press control + i

Answer (score 4):

If you want more than just indentation Xcode does not yet offer built in code formatting but you can use external tools like [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) to apply a consistent code style.

I described how I last set this up here: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/08/07/code-formatting-in-xcode/

Comment: The image link at that blog link is dead... Any instructions how to use this tool with Xcode?

Answer (score 3):

Turn on automatic code indentation, then <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. In other words, cut and paste in place. If your syntax is correct Xcode shouldn't have trouble formatting it (unless you're missing newlines).

Comment: Hey thanks for your response but can you tell me where i can fine Turn on automatic code indentation (In which tab). ?

Comment: @user532445: In the **Indentation** tab, check **Syntax-aware indenting**.

Comment: Preferences->Text Editing->Indentation->Tab key: "Indents allways" gives you sort of the behaviour you would expect

Comment: When you select code and press the [tab] key. You can't use the tab custom anymore though, but you can use spaces to position your code customary.

Answer (score 3):

There's a menu command:

**Edit** > **Format** > **Re-Indent**

I don't think there's a shortcut on it by default, but you can easily create one in the Key Bindings tab in the Xcode Preferences.

Comment: I find it quicker to just cut and paste (select, Cmd-X, Cmd-V).

Comment: You're right, it usually is faster to do a Cut and Paste if you don't set up a shortcut and you're proficient with your text selection key combos (which you should be if you're a programmer). If you do this regularly though, it may be less error-prone to use the actual command rather than relying on the side-effect of Xcode indenting your code when you do a Paste. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Use default, **"COMMAND ["** and **"COMMAND ]"**
Simple!

Answer (score 2):

as @McGordon says, Control + i works on indenting.

(As of Xcode 4.1) its there in the menu at

Editor --> Structure --> Re-Indent

Answer (score 2):

Select the text you want to Align And then press Control(ctrl)+I.

Answer (score 1):

The defaults way Xcode is set up is to use Control + i (also known as ⌃ + i)

If you want to change this then:

1. Open xcode preferences
2. Go to Keybindings
3. Search for "Indent"
4. Edit and change it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

=> Select All Code by `(command + A)`
=> Press `(control + ])` for indent.

Comment: Select All Code by (command + A) => Press (command + i) for Re-arrange.